# What is the most efficient way to find and print the duplicate values in arraylist?

Tags: java, collections

For Example,

I have an `ArrayList` like this,

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
list.add("D");
list.add("A");
list.add("C");
list.add("A");
list.add("D");
list.add("C");
list.add("D");
```

I just want to know is there any in built method to find the duplicate values.?

Comment: @MadPhysicist find and print

Comment: Then go with Surinder's solution. It's pretty elegant. Evgeniy's is too if you want to keep track of the numbers.

Comment: @PrabhakarManthena There is not such a method to find duplicates, HashSet were introduced in Java if you don't want duplicate elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method add of Set returns a boolean whether a value already exists (true if it does not exist, false if it already exists.

So just iterate through all the values:

```
public Set<Integer> findDuplicates(List<Integer> listContainingDuplicates)
{ 
  final Set<Integer> setToReturn = new HashSet(); 
  final Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet();

  for (Integer yourInt : listContainingDuplicates)
  {
   if (!set1.add(yourInt))
   {
    setToReturn.add(yourInt);
   }
  }
  return setToReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a method in ArrayList. You can use Map to detect duplicates.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
...
Integer n = map.get(s);
map.put(s, n == null ? 1 : n + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this.

```
int count = Collections.frequency(list,"A");
if(count>1)
System.out.println(count);
```

update

```
List<String> duplicates= new ArrayList<String>();
for (String string : list) {
       if(Collections.frequency(list,string)>1&&!duplicates.contains(string)){
            duplicates.add(string);
       }
}

System.out.println(duplicates);
```

**output**

```
[A, C, D]
```

Comment: Not really effective if you are planning on iterating through every value in the list, because you will get duplicate frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Set.add(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) return value for this. Add would return false if the set already contains the value being added. Here's how you'd use it:

```
void printDuplicates(List<String> data) {
  Set<String> uniques = new HashSet<String>(data.size() * 2);
  for (String s: data) {
    if (!uniques.add(s)) {
      System.out.println("Duplicate: " + s);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the `data.size() * 2` in `new HashSet<String>(data.size() * 2)`?

Comment: That constructor specifies initial capacity. I am pre-allocating space in the hashset so it does not need to ever grow. As a rule of thumb, its a good idea to tell the data structure how much data you are going to put in it if you happen to know. I'll admit, however, that the `* 2` might be an overkill, especially if you do expect a moderate ratio of elements to be duplicates; i.e. you could say `new HashSet(data.size(), 2.0f)` and prevent resizing.

Comment: On a philosophical note, I don't consider supplying this information a premature optimization, because the act of associating `uniques` with `data` during construction is not a hack, not difficult to do, and actually conveys the code author's expectation to a reader. It says that the author expects the two collections to be about the same size.